# How to put code in beamer two column

Tags: beamer, verbatim, two-column

I was trying to put code and a figure side by side in a `beamer` presentation. I tried two methods - one said in `beamer` documentation and other in standard LaTeX. But couldn't get the output. The two column thing works well if I don't have any code in it. I tried both `listings` and `verbatim`, with `fragile` option but in vein.

The code I gave was

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column[t]{5cm}
Two
\column[t]{5cm}
test
\end{columns}
```

This works well. But when I gave code with `fragile` option it gave error. Code without `fragile` option also gave error.

```
\begin[fragile]{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column[t]{5cm}
\begin{verbatim}
Two
\end{verbatim}
\column[t]{5cm}
test
\end{columns}
```

The error I got is (From Log file)

```
 [8
] [9
]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.100
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again>
\par
l.100
The `$' that I just saw supposedly matches a previous `$$'.
So I shall assume that you typed `$$' both times.
! You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.
\beamer@smuggle ...@zeropt \else \ifvmode \unskip
\fi \ifhmode \unskip \fi \...
l.102 \column
[t]{5cm}
Sorry...I usually can't take things from the current page.
Try `I\vskip-\lastskip' instead.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endframe ->\egroup
\begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
l.110 \end{frame}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
[10
]
\tf@nav=\write6
\openout6 = `latex.nav'.
\tf@toc=\write7
\openout7 = `latex.toc'.
\tf@snm=\write8
\openout8 = `latex.snm'.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{equation*} on input line 88 ended by \end{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
```

I also got error without code, with fragile option included.
I also tried the following but in vein

```
\begin[fragile]{frame}
\frametitle{Structure of a \LaTeX\ document}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{semiverbatim}
test
\end{semivrbatim}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{hello}
\end{column}
\end{frame}
\end{columns}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right syntax is

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
```

Here's your example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{columns}
\column[t]{5cm}
\begin{verbatim}
Two
\end{verbatim}
\column[t]{5cm}
test
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax is not correct: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`, not `\begin[fragile]{frame}`.

The following works (even if you replace the `verbatim` environment with `lstlisting` from [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Structure of a \LaTeX\ document}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
test code
here is some more stuff
172 192 d9a $^&2 ()%$
\end{verbatim}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```